# Elementary treatment of the Weibull distribution

Tags: references, intuition, weibull-distribution

I am looking for a reference to an elementary (or at least fairly simple) treatment of the Weibull-distribution. I have a bright high school student doing a project on wind mills and it turns out that wind speeds follow a Weibull distribution. Ideally I am looking for a derivation of the mean and standard deviations of a Windmill. A reference a proof of the fact, that the distribution in fact is a distribution would also be nice to see.

Comment: What sort of probability and calculus background are you assuming? Perhaps the easiest way to view a Weibull is as an Exponential under a certain transformation. In other words, it's like observing an exponential waiting time in a universe that "warps" how we experience time. Many of the properties of the Weibull "drop out" from this interpretation.

Comment: I am assuming very little prior knowledge of statistics apart from the definitions of mean and standard deviation. Calculus wise integration by substitution is fine to use. A proof using a detour via exponential distributions will be fine.

Comment: This http://www.weibull.nl/weibullstatistics.htm is close to what I want, but calculations of the descriptors are missing.

Comment: This note [Use of Probability Distribution Functions for Wind](http://www.csun.edu/~lcaretto/me483/probability.doc) by Larry Caretto contains an elementary treatment. I am still interested in more references.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using R this is how you could verify the distribution:

```
library(fitdistrplus)
#Generate fake data
shape <- 1.9
x <- rweibull(n=7000, shape=shape, scale=1)

#Fit x data with fitdist
fit.w <- fitdist(x, "weibull")
summary(fit.w)
plot(fit.w)
```

Here is a helpful research publication on wind and the Weibull distribution from Tufts: 
https://engineering.tufts.edu/cee/people/vogel/documents/probabilityDistributionsOffshoreWindSpeeds.pdf